# Why does one statement work and one not

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have a table in a database which I access like this:

```
+(NSMutableArray *) queryDatabaseWithSQL:(NSString *)sql params:(NSArray *)params {
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSMutableArray *rtn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int index = 0;
    NSString *filepath = [self copyDatabaseToDocumentsWithName:@"database"];
    if (sqlite3_open([filepath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if ([params count]) {
                for (int i = 0; i < [params count]; i++) {
                    NSString *obj = [params objectAtIndex:i];
                    sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStatement, i + 1, [obj UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                }
            }
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                index = 0;
                const char *s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, index);
                while (s) {
                    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:s]];
                    index++;
                    s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, index);
                }
                if (![rtn containsObject:arr]) {
                    [rtn addObject:arr];
                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return rtn;
}
```

This works fine when I call the function like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [database queryDatabaseWithSQL:@"SELECT * FROM FRIENDSUSERS WHERE USER = ?" params:@[[delegate->user objectForKey:@"username"]]]);
```

Then when I call the function using a string like this it doesn't return any rows:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [database queryDatabaseWithSQL:@"SELECT * FROM FRIENDSUSERS WHERE USER = ?" params:@[@"username"]]);
```

I haven't got a clue what is going one with but I have checked the strings match and they do so I'm now stuck

Can anyone see any reason why this would not work

I have run error checks as well and every time it returns no error, or rows :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the values in the `USER` column really blobs?

Comment: No but they don't need to be it works anyway though will check for you @CL.

Comment: Thanks man you were right make that answer @CL.